# SVNMailer - post commit end with "option -r: invalid integer value: "

Tags: svn

Hi recently I'm working to setup svn email notification also and I face problem. I'm using svnmailer and I get error `option -r: invalid integer value: ''`.

I try to google and can't find any clue to solve it. Need help here...

My post-commit config is as below:

```
/usr/bin/svn-mailer -c -f /scripts/mailer.conf -e "UTF-8" -r "$2" -d "$1"
```

when i run the post-commit it will show below message:

```
option -r: invalid integer value: ''
```

May I know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The error seemed to indicate it is unabled to parse quotation mark when expecting integer value. You might want to remove the quotation from the revision variable substitution.

> /usr/bin/svn-mailer -c -f /scripts/mailer.conf -e "UTF-8" -r $2 -d "$1"

Comment: I have removed it and now I get below error:
option -r: invalid integer value: '-d'
I also try to remove the quotation mark for repository as below: /usr/bin/svn-mailer -c -f /scripts/mailer.conf -e "UTF-8" -r $2 -d $1
Now I get error as below:                                               option -r: invalid integer value: '-d'

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest you remove the double quotes around -r, or replace it with --revision just in case its getting confused.

An alternative to debug it is to echo the command line to a file and then replay it manually. The revnum will be fixed in the postr-commit hook so you can edit the command as you like and re-run it to get an email of the given revnum.